# How to Plot target, actuals and achieved percentage in Tableau

Tags: graph, tableau-api

I have two fields with me. The target for sales and the actual sales. I am able to plot these two fields in Tableau using dual axis. However I need help in plotting the Achieved percentage (Actuals/Target *100) too.

Comment: How would you like to plot it? It sounds like you've created the field already, I'd suggest having all three on a chart would not be the best approach, so what would you ideally like to do?

Comment: I want all three in the same chart. Target as Gantt, Actuals as bars 
and the achieved % as line. The dual axis is working with either of the fields combined but unable to put all three in one chart.

Comment: Are you able to share a sample workbook? You may just be able to drag the pill onto a single side of the axis.

Answer (score 0):

Use measure values and measure names to plot target and actuals on the same axis (aka a blended axis). The easiest way is to first plot one measure (say targets), and then drop the additional measure onto the same axis (not the shelf, the actual axis). When you see two light green bars over the cursor before you release the mouse, you're doing the right thing.

Then drag your percentage field to the opposite side of the chart to make a dual axis.

So one axis is for the (multiple) measures that are specified in dollars, and the second axis is for the single measure that is specified in percentages.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I created a new chart for the % field and it helps in the dashboard. Thanks to you and Ben for your time.

Comment: Glad to help. Best way to thank someone on stack overflow is to upvote and accept the answer.